# Firebase filter by field and sort by another field

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database in Firebase with the following data:

```
{
    user: 1;
    points: 100;
},
{
    user: 1;
    points: 510;
},
{
    user: 2;
    points: 110;
},
{
    user: 1;
    points: 85;
},
{
    user: 3;
    points: 300;
},
{
    user: 1;
    points: 500;
}
```

How can I make a query so that it only shows the fields of user 1 sorted from highest to lowest with REST queries?

I have tried with

```
https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/tirada.json?orderBy="user"&equalTo="1"
```

And it returns filtered by User but without sorting by Points

```
    {
        user: 1;
        points: 100;
    },
    {
        user: 1;
        points: 510;
    },
    {
        user: 1;
        points: 85;
    },
    {
        user: 1;
        points: 500;
    }
```

I need this result

```
{
        user: 1;
        points: 85;
    },
    {
        user: 1;
        points: 100;
    },
    {
        user: 1;
        points: 500;
    },
    {
        user: 1;
        points: 510;
    }
```

Thank's

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: You may consider using Firestore (instead of the Realtime database), which allows ordering by multiple fields, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. In your case that would translate to a property `"user_points": "1_510"` that you can then order/filter on. 
But the REST API returns raw JSON objects, and the order of properties in a JSON object is undefined. So this means that you'll have to sort the results on the point value in your client-side code anyway. Given that, you might as well stick to only filtering on `user` anyway.

Also see:

- [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)
- [Firebase returning keys of child node in different orders on different devices/Android versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808990/firebase-returning-keys-of-child-node-in-different-orders-on-different-devices-a)